# How to make sharp/"convert" edges with the width tool?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, drawing

I am using Illustrator and am trying to make a tunnel of light going through lenses and the width tool has been fantastic. However, it makes the outline too smooth. Is there any way to make it more rigid/angular?

I'd like to use the convert tool at each width point, for example.

Below is what I'm getting and what I'm after.

[image]

Comment: The Width Tool won't do that easily. You'd be better off expanding the stroke and then altering the resulting shape.

Comment: But you can only alter each side? The width tool does exactly what I want but it's just curved rather than angular.

Comment: @Metis as the question has been reopened feel free to make an actual answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not something you can easily (at all?) do with a stroke and the width tool.

You'd be better off drawing the shape manually; you can draw one half and use a Transform effect (*Effect → Distort & Transform → Transform...*) to mirror that, you then only have to edit one half and the other will mirror it exactly. Just add the effect, set 1 copy, Reflect Y and change the transform origin:

[image]

If you want a stroke around the whole thing (as in your example) you can group the path and add a stroke from the Appearance panel *below* the "contents" of the group (if you set the stroke on the initial object you'll get the stroke running through the middle too), just set the correct fill on the object itself then add the stroke through the Appearance panel:

[image]